# Set Automatic Proxy Configuration on a per-network basis?

Tags: network, wifi, proxy

My company's Wi-Fi network requires that I use an Automatic Proxy Configuration (setting in the Advanced Network Settings) to access external websites.

However, I don't want to use the proxy when connecting to my home Wi-Fi network.

In the Network settings, I created a Work location which uses the proxy, and a Home location which does not, but this requires that I manually switch my location every time I go to work or go home.

Is there a way to use the automatic proxy whenever I connect to my work network, and not use the automatic proxy on all other networks? Or some other way that does not require manually setting my location twice a day?

Comment: https://github.com/eprev/locationchanger

Comment: You have to slightly modify some parts of it.